# How to convert integer list to map removing duplicates?

Tags: list, scala, for-loop

Let's say that I have a Map of strings -> List of Integers. I would like to create a function which takes in as a parameter a List of strings and returns all the integers correlating to all the string in that list. I.e. if the Map X contains the following mappings:

```
database = [("Bob",[1,2,3]),("John",[1,5,6]),("Trevor",[4,5,7])]
```

If this function takes in ["Bob","John"] as the list of names, it should return,

```
[1,2,3,5,6]
```

Since Bob correlates to 1,2,3 and John correlates to 1,5,6 (same entries for both names aren't duplicated). I also would like to not introduce a mutable variable if I don't have to, thus leading me to believe a for comprehension that yields this list of number values would be the best way to achieve this, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use a `for-comprehension` you can so this:

```
val result = for {
  key <- keys
  nums <- map.get(key).toSeq
  num <- nums
} yield num

result.distinct
```

Explanation:

for each key in the list try to get an entry and convert it to a `Seq` (necessary because flatMap expects a `Seq` in this case) and add every number in the list to the result. If the key is not present in the map the collection will be empty and therefore not yield any results. At the end call `distinct` to remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

```
val myMap = Map("Bob" -> List(1,2,3), "John" -> List(1,5,6), "Trevor" -> List(4,5,7))
val names = List("Bob", "John")
```

You can add default value to `Map` using method `withDefaultValue`:

```
val mapWithDefaul = myMap withDefaultValue Nil
```

Then you could use `Map` as function in `flatMap`:

```
names.flatMap(mapWithDefaul).distinct
// List(1, 2, 3, 5, 6)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let

```
val db = Map("Bob" -> List(1,2,3), "John" -> List(1,5,6), "Trevor" -> List(4,5,7))
val names = List("Bob", "John")
```

Then a similar approach to @senia's using `flatMap`,

```
implicit class mapCorr[A,B](val db: Map[A,List[B]]) extends AnyVal {
  def corr(keys: List[A]): List[B] = {
    keys.flatMap{ k => db get k }.flatten.distinct
  }
}
```

and

```
scala> db.corr(keys)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 5, 6)
```

Here we allow for key lists of type `A` and maps from type `A` to type `List[B]` .

Answer (score 1):

```
val myset = Set("Bob","John")
val database = Map(("Bob"->List(1,2,3)),("John"->List(1,5,6)),("Trevor"->List(4,5,7)))

val ids = database.filter(m => myset.contains(m._1)).map(_._2).flatten.toList.distinct
```

outputs:

```
ids: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 5, 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
val result = database.filter(elem => list.contains(elem._1)).foldLeft(List())((res,elem) => res ++ elem._2)
```

where list is the input list of names.